# Understanding ARKit worldPosition of ARAnchor

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

After reading the ARKit documentation I was under the impression that `SCNNode.worldPosition` was the position of a node in the global Scene and would thus not change when the device is moved. However, when using `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` to track images in the scene the anchor nodes of the images changes position when the device is moving around (even though the images are stationary). Is this expected behavior?

The AR-session is configured like

```swift
func resetTracking() {
        
        guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else {
            fatalError("Missing expected asset catalog resources.")
        }
        
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 4
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
        session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```

and the position is tracked in

```swift
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        print(node.worldPosition)
}
```